# How can I call a WCF service from code, in the .net framework 3

Tags: vb.net, wcf, proxy-server

I'm working in VB.Net and I'm trying to make a piece of code more generic.

In fact, there's a big Select Case statement that build a ProxyServer based on a value passed in parameter (a string).

```
 Select Case _strNteraHL7
        Case Constantes.NomPRPMIN306010
            strUrl = ObtenirUrl("ProviderDetailsQuery", _strVersion, _strEnvir, True, _blnSimulCAIS, _blnSimulPDS, _blnSimulPDSSIIR, _blnSimulPDSInteg)
            objWsHL7 = New wsProviderDetailsQuery.ProviderDetailsQueryClient(objBinding, New EndpointAddress(strUrl))
        Case Constantes.NomPRPMIN301010
            strUrl = ObtenirUrl("AddProvider", _strVersion, _strEnvir, True, _blnSimulCAIS, _blnSimulPDS, _blnSimulPDSSIIR, _blnSimulPDSInteg)
            objWsHL7 = New wsAddProvider.AddProviderClient(objBinding, New EndpointAddress(strUrl))
```

The objects like "wsAddProvider" and "wsProviderDetailsQuery" in the previous example are service references that have been added through the GUI of Visual Studio...

What I want to know, is basically, if I can call this constructor from a certain pool containing service references, similar as when I want to call a control in a controls container...

for example:

> objWsHL7 = new wcfServicesContainer("serviceNameHere", paramArray())

or something similar, so I can remove all those big switch cases, that repeat the same thing 30 times.

objWsHL7 being an object or type "object" at compiling.

Sorry if I didn't mention enough detail, feel free to let me know if you need more, I don't really know what information I have to provide for this.

Edit: I've spotted another piece of code here that uses similar calls, maybe it'll help understanding...

Again, in another switch case statement,

```
objMsgHL7Out = _objWsHL7.ProviderDetailsQuery(_objMsgIn)
```

objMsgHL7Out is a System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
_objMsgIn is a System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
_objWsHL7 is an Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Create a hashmap of `HashMap<string, string>`
- Add `Constantes.NomPRPMIN306010`, ... as key and `"AddProvider"`, ... as value.
- call `ObtenirUrl(hashmap[_strNteraHL7], ...`

Comment: Good idea, I wanted to do something similar to what you've suggested, however, I'm using a Sqlite file for our config file. And I'd like to have a way to associate my constant string to a service (Most likely, I want to associate a string to a string that identifies a service..)

Comment: I think I've thought of a way I could do what I want, with a compromise of what I wanted at the beginning and what you've suggested, thanks.